# use getvar for both upper case and lower case

Tags: php

I have this code which i use now:

```
function onAfterInitialise(){
    $this->username = JRequest::getVar('user', null);
    $this->password = JRequest::getVar('passw', null);

    if(empty($this->username) || empty($this->password))  return true;

    $result = $this->params->get('authmethod','1') === '0' ? $this->plainLogin() : $this->encryptLogin();

    $redirectURL = $this->params->get('urlredirect', null);
    if(!empty($redirectURL)){
        if(!JError::isError($result)){
            $app = JFactory::getApplication();
            $app->redirect($redirectURL);
        }
    }
}
```

I want it to get the var even if it is `user` or `USER` and also for `passw` or `PASSW`.

How to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Easiest way is to check whether `$username` and `$password` are empty. If yes, then check for uppercase. If still empty, proceed as you've done now.

Comment: can u please add the the if to the code?

Comment: It's almost literally in the code already? Anyway, I'll write up an answer

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter is the default value and its default value is `null`. So as long as there are only 2 options - and not stuff like `User` as well - you can simply do:

```
$this->username = JRequest::getVar('user', JRequest::getVar('USER'));
$this->password = JRequest::getVar('passw', JRequest::getVar('PASSWD'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some additional checks to the code:

```
$this->username = JRequest::getVar('user', null);
if (empty($this->username)) {
    $this->username = JRequest::getVar('USER', null);
}

$this->password = JRequest::getVar('passw', null);
if (empty($this->password)) {
    $this->password= JRequest::getVar('PASSW', null);
}

// And then proceed as in your code
if(empty($this->username) || empty($this->password))  return true;
```

Comment: Updated, was missing closing parenteses.